# How to start working on Data Science Projects

Tags: data-science-model

As a beginner how to start working on Data Science projects because while working on the projects we want to know whether we are working on the right path or not and is there any guidelines there for to follow up ?

How to measure our performance regarding working on projects ?

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point for all newbies is **Kaggle**. It is a platform for budding and experienced data scientists where you can start learning data science from scratch if you are a newbie (there are Kaggle tutorials for this purpose) or you can take part in Kaggle competitions where you can gauge where you stand against other people.

Another great option is **Youtube** tutorials. There are literally hundreds of tutorials on virtually every topic you could imagine in data science/data analysis. Also they will provide you with proper guidelines and best practices to follow in data science.

There is plenty of material on the internet for data science be it articles, videos or competitions. Just select one or two platform and start without wasting too much time on gathering the materials or choosing which platform to start!

**Cheers!**